# Count how many documents have an attribute or are missing that attribute in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

How can I write a single Elasticsearch query that will count how many documents either have a value for a field or are missing that field?

This query successfully count the docs **missing** the field:

```
POST localhost:9200//<index_name_here>/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "Missing_Field" : {
            "missing": { "field": "group_doc_groupset_id" }
        }
    }
}
```

This query does the opposite, counting documents **NOT missing** the field:

```
POST localhost:9200//<index_name_here>/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "Not_Missing_Field" : {
            "exists": { "field": "group_doc_groupset_id" }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write one that combines both? For example, this yields a syntax error:

```
POST localhost:9200//<index_name_here>/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "Missing_Field_Or_Not" : {
            "missing": { "field": "group_doc_groupset_id" },
            "exists": { "field": "group_doc_groupset_id" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aggs operate on query scope, make bool query with "must" exist clause OR "must_not" exist clause and then aggregate.

Comment: Great advice which goes beyond my limited knowledge of elasticsearch. Can you post an example? I have used a Bool query in a filter but never in an aggregate.

Comment: actually, if you just need the count, you don't need aggs at all. just make query and use size=0, you will have number of documents matching the query, if you need further buckets on the results, then add aggs clause.

Comment: If you're count how many documents either have the field or are missing the field, aren't you just counting total documents?

Comment: you're right, I misunderstood the original intent

Answer (score 3):

```
GET indexname/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "a1": {
      "missing": {
        "field": "status"
      }
    },
    "a2": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "status"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured how to perform multiple aggregations as you suggested. It took me three days to master the syntax. Horrendous learning curve!

Comment: I highly recommend the book "elasticsearch, definitive guide" by Clinton Gormley and Zachary Tong

Answer (score 0):

As per [new Elastic search recommendation in the docs:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

```
GET {your_index_name}/_search     #or _count, to see just the value
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {    # here can be also "must"
        "exists": {
          "field": "{field_to_be_searched}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: _count allows to have exact values of how many documents are indexed. If there're more than 10k the total is shown as:

```
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,     # 10k
      "relation" : "gte"   # Greater than
    }
```